# React on directory changes on Linux in C

Tags: c, linux, directory, linux-kernel, inotify

I was wonder if it is possible to react on directory changes in C, like using an extended task or an interrupt without check the metadata every second?

I know that there is the VFC but there are only syscalls I can use in C. I really don't know enough about Linux to help my self for this question. Sould I using a driver to work on the Kernel Layer or is it possible on the User Layer.

Comment: You want [inotify](https://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify).